# React app not loading in AWS ECS Cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-ecs

I have the following dockerfile:

```
# Multi-stage
# 1) Node image for building frontend assets
# 2) nginx stage to serve frontend assets

# Name the node stage "builder"
FROM node:10 AS builder
# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app
# Copy all files from current directory to working dir in image
COPY . .
# install node modules and build assets
RUN yarn install && yarn build

# nginx state for serving content
FROM nginx:alpine
# Set working directory to nginx asset directory
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
# Remove default nginx static assets
RUN rm -rf ./*
# Copy static assets from builder stage
COPY --from=builder /app/build .
# Containers run nginx with global directives and daemon off
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

This works locally with docker.

I am using a T2.micro ec2 instance with a ecs cluster. The deployment of the service was successful and the task is running for the container image. I have tried going to the ec2 instance's public address and it returns took to long to respond. Let me know if you need any other details.

Thoughts?

Comment: Since you're compiling the application to static files anyways, can you push them into an S3 bucket, avoiding Docker/ECS entirely?  You do not need the final `ENTRYPOINT` line (Docker will inherit an identical `CMD` from the `nginx` base image) and it's not impossible that's causing problems.

Comment: It could be a bunch of things (perhaps some Security Group configurations that do not let the flow through). Depending what LB you are using there could be SG at the LB level. Depending on what networking mode you are using you may have SG either at the task level or EC2 instance level. If you are not deep into ECS you may want to deploy this application using [Copilot](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/getting-started/first-app-tutorial/) which will abstract all these details for you.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go the route suggested by @David Maze and store it in an S3 bucket instead of using ECS for the website.

I followed this guide and it is working:
https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/deploying-a-react-app-to-aws.html